# Why the massive overhead in a visual studio install

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I install visual studio 2013 ultimate on a x64, and i get with is components from 2005 and a whole bunch for x86 ?!

Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 redistributable x86

It also , if i am  not mistaken, gives me a version of visual studio 2010 as well as tooling and files only associated for those versions. There was no option to negate this. Do i really need all of this?

Comment: Is this the express or the commercial edition? I know that the express edition installs 50 things without asking you. Like: SQL Server and so on. After the installation you can spend half an hour removing all unwanted programs...

Comment: Microsoft fills up your hard drive so that you have less room for pirated movies (Apparently a conspiracy by the MPAA). If you install 2013 it doesn't install VS 2012, 2010, 2008, and 2005. It may though install some of the files associated with those releases (like redistributables)

Comment: I installed 2013 ultimate. Update the post. I have a ssd so its not space or memory issue. Its just .. a why are they doing it? I am having a problem with iis now, and i am trying to figure out the source of the problem in and amongst a bunch of stuff that seems completely unnecessary

Comment: @MichaelPetch It does install visual studio 2010 and then redistributables for 2008 2005. I also have blend, which i never use. I would really just like vs just a small clean install. I would install vs express but then i cannot add extensions which i use

Comment: @gerdi Is this a fully genuine installation of VS2013 from Microsoft? If not, it may have been repacked to include more components from previous versions.

Comment: I've been using genuine MS Visual Studio/MSDN since 1997 and I must admit I haven't seen your behavior with any of the products including my VS2013.

Comment: @cybermonkey It is genuine install for work. I am going to close this question because i do see there is an option for customization that i seemed to have overlooked on the initial install. I have reinstalled VS with most of the extras turned off. I would really like light version though, I work mostly in javascript so a lot of the hardcore dev stuff never gets touched. Still getting some SQL Server stuff which i am never going to use.